Visual Studio displays error "a declaration cannot have a label" but the project still compiles
I've made the following MRE to represent the problem:
typedef struct {
    char data[64];
} Message;

int main()
{
    int type = 1;
    switch (type)
    {
    case 1:
        Message m = { "hello world" };
        printf("%s\n", m.data);

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

The IDE underlines Message in red and displays an error "Error (active) E1072: a declaration cannot have a label", but the build succeeds and the program runs. Why is that and/or how can I solve the error?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit), version 17.9.1

What compilation error do you get? Do you get error C2361: initialization of 'm' is skipped by 'default' label? If you do, I guess you are using a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler. Replace your case 1: with case 1: { Message m = {"hello world"}; printf("%s\n", m.data); break; } - If you don't get any errors when compiling, just ignore IntelliSense.

@TedLyngmo actually I didn't get any compilation error, just that E1072: a declaration cannot have a label. If I check the compiler in the VS project properties, I see "C Language Standard: Default (Legacy MSVC)", with some additional info such as "Determines the C language standard the compiler will enforce. It is recommended to use the latest version when possible. (/std:c11, /std:c17)"

Ok, if you want to get rid of the IntelliSense-warning, always place declarations in switches in {...} blocks like I showed above. It may be clearer here

@TedLyngmo that was it! It's simpler than I thought, thank you :)

Note that in C23, when that's finally released, you will be able to label declarations as well as statements — so the code would be valid in C23.  See also GCC on Mixed Labels and Declarations.

You could also fix it by adding a null statement (just a semicolon) between the label and the declaration. But it is better to put the declaration inside a compound statement (block) as recommended by @TedLyngmo.

As suggested by Ted Lyngmo in the comments section, the simplest solution is to surround switch declarations with curly brackets:
switch (type)
{
case 1:
{
    Message m = { "hello world" };
    printf("%s\n", m.data);

    break;
}
default:
    break;
}

